# UI Grid Custom Checkbox styling

Tags: angularjs, templates, checkbox, angular-ui-grid

I am attempting to do some styling with the checkboxes in UI-Grid and it doesn't seem to be working properly. Notice the checkbox is still appearing underneath my styling overlay, and clicking on the 3rd checkbox seems to activate the overlay checkbox style.

Is there any way to replace the checkbox appearing in the column with my overlay and use that instead? Or does anyone have an idea to get this working properly?

http://plnkr.co/edit/fMMq71849pxE0NLcfuVJ

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">' +
                                         '  <input type="checkbox" class= "Check" id="Check" name="select_item" value = "true" ng-model="row.entity.ValidateProvider"/>' +
                                         '  <label for="roundedOne" />' +
                                         '  </div>'
```

I want to get them looking like the 4th from the top on this site:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that.

In UI Grid, we usually uses `blur` event of HTML input control to end cell edit, which should be the best user experience. However currently there is no suitable CSS support to style custom checkbox, and to properly dispatch `blur` event at the same time. In the example mentioned, you can see the css rule to make `blur' impossible:

```
input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden; }
```

There is a non-standard css property `appearance` to use, which can work at this time, instead of `visibility` and others, but needs careful test on browsers. No support on any IE.

Also, `editableCellTemplate` should be used rather than `cellTemplate` for edit.